# Upload a prebuilt file to Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics

I am trying to automate our build/release process. I am specifically concerned with the Android app at the moment, but I may also need to extend similar support for our iOs app.

Until now, all uploads to Crashlytics have been triggered with crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease. However we are now building and testing the apk first, then looking to upload that same pre-built apk to Crashlytics. The new process means we need a way of uploading the apk to Crashlytics directly, without having any dependencies on rebuilding or being within the project's directory.

I can see that I can do this through Android Studio by dragging and dropping the apk. Is there a command line tool or script that I can use to automate something similar from our build machine?

Comment: FYI Should anyone find this useful. Here's the response from the Crashlytics team: "Awesome question and right now there isn't a way to upload the same .APK from the command line, we do hook into the build tools at build time to upload the .APK. You could use the IDE plugins to upload the same .apk, but I'll let the team know you'd like to see this from the command line as well!"

Answer (score 1):

This operation is not currently supported. See my comment above for the response from the Crashlytics team